# Subset data.frame by date

Tags: r, date, subset

I have a dataset called `EPL2011_12`. I would like to make new a dataset by subsetting the original  by date.  The dates are in the column named `Date`  The dates are in DD-MM-YY format.

I have tried

```
EPL2011_12FirstHalf <- subset(EPL2011_12, Date > 13-01-12)
```

and

```
EPL2011_12FirstHalf <- subset(EPL2011_12, Date > "13-01-12")
```

but get this error message each time.

> ```
> Warning message:
> In Ops.factor(Date, 13- 1 - 12) : > not meaningful for factors
> ```

I guess that means R is treating like text instead of a number and that why it won't work?

Comment: It means your Date column was read in as a factor (presumably when using `read.table` or some similar function). You'll need to convert it using e.g. `as.Date`.

Comment: Don't forget `as.character()`, eg use `as.Date(as.character(X), "%d-%m-%y")`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Isn't there an `as.Date.factor` method, or am I misunderstanding what that does...?

Comment: Interesting. That must be new-ish. I had been bitten so often by `as.Date(factorvar)` in the past with `factorvar` becoming its levels...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well, it's clearly not a number since it has dashes in it. The error message and the two comments tell you that it is a factor but the commentators are apparently waiting and letting the message sink in. Dirk is suggesting that you do this:

```
 EPL2011_12$Date2 <- as.Date( as.character(EPL2011_12$Date), "%d-%m-%y")
```

After that you can do this:

```
 EPL2011_12FirstHalf <- subset(EPL2011_12, Date2 > as.Date("2012-01-13") )
```

R date functions assume the format is either "YYYY-MM-DD" or "YYYY/MM/DD". You do need to compare like classes: date to date,  or character to character. And if you were comparing character-to-character, then it's only going to be successful if the dates are in the YYYYMMDD format (with identical delimiters if any delimiters are used).

Comment: If there are other date types like 2013/01/01 13:34:59 you may refer to https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html for more format detail.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing you should do with date variables is confirm that R reads it as a Date. To do this, for the variable (i.e. vector/column) called Date, in the data frame called EPL2011_12, input

`class(EPL2011_12$Date)`

The output should read [1] "Date". If it doesn't, you should format it as a date by inputting

`EPL2011_12$Date <- as.Date(EPL2011_12$Date, "%d-%m-%y")`

Note that the hyphens in the date format ("%d-%m-%y") above can also be slashes ("%d/%m/%y"). Confirm that R sees it as a Date. If it doesn't, try a different formatting command

`EPL2011_12$Date <- format(EPL2011_12$Date, format="%d/%m/%y")`

Once you have it in Date format, you can use the `subset` command, or you can use brackets

`WhateverYouWant <- EPL2011_12[EPL2011_12$Date > as.Date("2014-12-15"),]`