# How do I get pass the '<' not meaningful for factors error in R?

Tags: r

I am really new to R and I am attempting my first piece of code, I think it will work so long as I can get pass this error:

```
> EVP_Daily_Input = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Hicks\\Desktop\\EVP_Daily_Input.csv", sep =",")
> 
> TEST_SET_BEGIN <- "01/10/2018"
> 
> myTrainSet <- EVP_Daily_Input %>% filter(Date < TEST_SET_BEGIN)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Date, TEST_SET_BEGIN) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R subset by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471640/r-subset-by-date)

Comment: In the future, it would be helpful to give a sample of your data, so that answers don't need to make too many assumptions regarding its structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two steps. First, `read.csv` automatically changes string columns into factors. To avoid that, do:

```
EVP_Daily_Input = read.csv("C:\\Users\\Hicks\\Desktop\\EVP_Daily_Input.csv", sep =",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then, you need to translate these strings into actual date format:

```
EVP_Daily_Input$Date<- as.Date(EVP_Daily_Input$Date)
```

(depending on how your data is set up, you might need to add "format=" and specify the format of the dates. See `?strptime` for more information on specifying the format of dates.)

Do the same to your TEST_SET_BEGIN:

```
TEST_SET_BEGIN <- as.Date("2018/10/01")
```

Now you should be good to go. Good luck!

Comment: Adding `stringsAsFactors` will probably not solve the problem, since user is looking to subset using a binary operator. The only difference this will make is that when coercing to date, `as.character` is not needed.

Comment: True, but I view it as a best practice to avoid factors unless we specifically want them. It's also something a new R user is not likely to know about, so I thought it was worth including.