# Subsetting a data frame by specific dates after using as.character(as.Date()) to convert original factor variable Date column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, as.date

I'm very new to R and am trying out some practice problems. I have a large dataset from which I need to create a smaller dataset by a date range. I am having difficulty doing so and it's probably because I don't have a good understanding of what these R commands do.

Here is the first six lines of the dataset `rawdata`:

```
Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage
1 16/12/2006 17:24:00               4.216                 0.418 234.840
2 16/12/2006 17:25:00               5.360                 0.436 233.630
3 16/12/2006 17:26:00               5.374                 0.498 233.290
4 16/12/2006 17:27:00               5.388                 0.502 233.740
5 16/12/2006 17:28:00               3.666                 0.528 235.680
6 16/12/2006 17:29:00               3.520                 0.522 235.020
  Global_intensity Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
1           18.400          0.000          1.000             17
2           23.000          0.000          1.000             16
3           23.000          0.000          2.000             17
4           23.000          0.000          1.000             17
5           15.800          0.000          1.000             17
6           15.000          0.000          2.000             17
```

I would like to create a subset of this data where the dates run from 02/01/2007 - 02/02/2007.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14471640/11424667), I found the suggestion to first run the as.Date function (and as.character function if necessary) and then a subset function.

So to start, I converted the "Date" column from factors to characters using as.character(rawdata$Date). Realizing that this generated a whole list of data, I assigned it to the object CharDate as follows:

```
CharDate <- as.character(rawdata$Date)
```

Then, I converted the data again using as.Date, intending to use this to subset my rawdata, assigning it to DateasDate.

```
DateasDate <- as.Date(CharDate, "%d/%m/%y")
```

At this point, I'm confused as to how to use this to subset my original file `rawdata`, since isn't `DateasDate` a new variable? Would I have to add `DateasDate` as a column to `rawdata`? Is there any way I can make changes to the Date column in `rawdata` directly so I wouldn't have to do that?

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: @RonakShah so sorry about that, I've edited it and hopefully this makes more sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first convert the `Date` object to actual date and then `subset` the dataframe.

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
subset(df, Date >= as.Date("2007-01-02") & Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02"))
```

Or using the same logic with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y") %>%
  filter(Date >= as.Date("2007-01-02") & Date <= as.Date("2007-02-02"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I never knew that I could modify variables by assigning functions to them this way, this is really helpful! The first line `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/"%m/%y")` worked beautifully, however the subset function did not work, generating an error message that reads, "Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format".

Comment: @abbylim you copied the first line incorrectly. Can you do `df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")` and then check. Note the `"%d/%m/%Y"` specifically.

Comment: Ahh! After fixing that there isn't an error message anymore, but the subset ended up being an empty data frame with 0 rows? The same thing happened when I tried doing `subset(rawdata, Date == as.Date("2007-02-01") | Date == as.Date("2007-02-02"))`.

Comment: weird..can you tell me what output do you get when you do 1) `class(rawdata$Date)`, 2) `min(rawdata$Date)` and 3) `max(rawdata$Date)` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry I realized it was because I was typing "2002-02-02" instead of "2002-2-2"...... Thank you so much for all your patience and help!!!